How do I iterate over a sublist of a SynchronizedList in Java?
What kind of synchronization should I use to iterate over a sublist returned from a SynchronizedList as a result of subList() method invocation?
The documentation for Collections.synchronizedList()  says:

...
It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it:
  List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
      ...
  synchronized (list) {
      Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
      while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
  }


As I understand from the source code, SynchronizedList can use a different mutex which is not this. In particular, it happens when SynchronizedList is a sublist. Does it mean that the following example uses the wrong synchronization provided that List subList = synchronizedList.subList(2, 5);? Isn't it worth to be mentioned in the documentation?
synchronized (subList) {
    Iterator i = subList.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
        foo(i.next());
}


Your analysis is correct. You are indeed synchronising on the wrong object. Not sure if this counts as an answer, but it could be argued that your code is not doing what the documentation says you should. By iterating through the sublist, you are "iterating over it", where "it" refers to the list returned by synchronizedList. But you did not "synchronize on the returned list" because the sublist and original list are different objects and have different monitors.

Then this API is rather inconvenient and error-prone, isn't it? A client is forced to additionally pass a reference to the original "parent" list each time it is required to iterate over the sublist.

You could use forEach. That will synchronize on the correct mutex internally for the entire iteration. The downside being there's no great way to stop the iteration part way.

Well how else would you design such an API? If the sublist and the original list synchronises on different objects, thread safety goes out of the window, doesn't it? Use something in the java.util.concurrent package if synchronizedList is unsuitable.
